# How to appendChild an UL to a SPAN?

Tags: javascript, web

So, if we're going to append a LI to UL we should do this:

```
var list = document.createElement('li');
var ulist = document.createElement('ul');
ulist.appendChild(list);
```

what if I create a span, should I do this?

```
var list = document.createElement('li');
var ulist = document.createElement('ul);
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(ulist);
ulist.appendChild(list);
```

Comment: The source code you have provided has a syntax error `document.createElement('ul);` **=>** `document.createElement('ul');`

Comment: then teach me how

Comment: *"then teach me how"* I have clearly pointed out the syntax error with the correction but if you look at **T.J. Crowder**'s answer you will find the bigger issue with that you are trying to do.

Comment: That simple mistake can make the difference of things working and not working.

Answer (score 1):

That's the sort of thing you'd do, yes (other than the typo — missing closing `'`), **except** [`span`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-span-element) elements cannot contain [`ul`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-ul-element) elements. The content model of `span` is [*phrasing content*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#phrasing-content-2), but `ul` can only be used where [*flow content*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#flow-content-2) is expected.

Comment: Are there any other ways?

Comment: @RonchiMiong - Other ways to do what? You haven't said what you want to do (other than saying you wanted to add a `ul` to a `span`).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quote after ul, but your code is correct.

In your latter code, you are appending a `<li>` to a `<ul>` and this same `<ul>` to a `<span>`. You may want to append all this to the body to make them appear. See example below:

```js
const list = document.createElement('li');
const ulist = document.createElement('ul');
const span = document.createElement('span');

span.appendChild(ulist);
ulist.appendChild(list);

document.body.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: Except, of course, that `ul` isn't a valid child for `span`.

Comment: So only li is a valid child for ul?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed, but the code *is* doing that and browsers would not complain either :)

Comment: @RonchiMiong This the UL HTML specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/ul.html -- As per this document, the "Permitted parent elements" are "Any element that can contain flow elements". If you check span specs you will see that it can only contain phrasing elements: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/common-models.html#common.elem.flow

Comment: @RonchiMiong Now, on your last question, you are asking whether li is the only possible child of ul. The answer to that, as per the previous link is also yes. However, careful, on your code you were using span as a parent; not as a child of ul.

Comment: @nitobuendia - You can't rely on what browsers do when you create invalid structures like that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Partially agreed. First, I agree that this is invalid syntax and should not be done. That being said, the logic of appending elements is correct, which is my understanding of Ronchi's question. Now, HTML specifications usually do explain how to handle errors. For example, for parse errors: "error handling for parse errors is well-defined" (although most times non-normative). Some examples: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser Similar behaviours are usually defined for other type of errors.